# Spring 4 Spring Security 3.2.2 No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I know this has been asked a lot, but none of the answers seem to actually work for me. I've been banging my head against Spring Security for the last two days and had zero luck. The documentation claims it's super easy to setup, but I can't help but feel like it is missing something.

My web.xml:

```
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>SpringProject</display-name>

    <!-- Spring Configuration Files -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath*:mvcDispatcher-servlet.xml
            classpath*:application-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Spring Security Filters -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
             org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
        </filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- Spring Listeners -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- MVC Filter -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvcDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvcDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

And my application-security.xml:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">

    <global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />

    <http use-expressions="true">
        <form-login login-page="/login"
                    login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
                    default-target-url="/view"
                    authentication-failure-url="/login?login_error=t" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="isAnonymous()" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userService" />
    </authentication-manager>

    <user-service id="userService">
        <user name="user" password="password" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    </user-service>

</beans:beans>
```

When I deploy (to WAS8.0) and attempt to get to my login page, I get the error:

`com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[mvcDispatcher]: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined`

If I change web.xml from:

```
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            classpath*:mvcDispatcher-servlet.xml
            classpath*:application-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
```

to:

```
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            WEB-INF/mvcDispatcher-servlet.xml
            WEB-INF/application-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
```

I get the error

`[Servlet Error]-[mvcDispatcher]: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/security]`

I have no idea what is causing this or why Spring Security is not working here. It's been incredibly frustrating. Any assistance is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Where do you place application-security.xml? Is it on the classpath?  Seems that application-security.xml is not loaded.

Comment: It is at WEB-INF/application-security.xml

Comment: Is mvcDispatcher-servlet.xml also in WEB-INF directory? (WEB-INF/mvcDispatcher-servlet.xml)

Comment: Yes it is. If I drop the classpath*: from both of those entries, I get `java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/mvcDispatcher-servlet.xml]`

Comment: Okay, I have post my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following in your web.xml.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/application-security.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

**Note:**

- The WEB-INF directory is not on the classpath.
- The DispatcherServlet looks for WEB-INF/[servlet-name]-servlet.xml by default.

Comment: I made that change, which gives me the error:

`Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/security] Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/application-security.xml]`

Comment: Try removing `-3.0` from your xml schema url. `spring-security.xsd` instead of `spring-security-3.0.xsd`.

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much! Ive been yankin my hair out trying to get this to work.